# How to skip one column and add string to another column in listview?

Tags: delphi

We create a listview with 5 columns. In one function we add data in first 3 cols in sequence. In the second function we want to add string to the fifth col. Column 4 may be blank or filled before the second function. We just want to skip that column and add data in the fifth. Or the question may be boiled down to checking the fourth col' value. How to check it ? We tried 
if listview.items[i].SubItems.Strings[2]=''..., It will prompt out of bounds.

Please give some advice on it. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot `skip` a column in a [`TListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TListView) when you use the item.SubItems property, but you can assign an empty string to a column.

you must proceed like this:

first always fill your columns when you add a new [`TItemList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/ComCtrls.TListItem).

```
item:=listview.Items.Add();
item.captiom:='Data col1';
item.SubItems.Add('Data col2'); 
item.SubItems.Add('Data col3'); 
item.SubItems.Add('');//empty
item.SubItems.Add('');//empty
```

then in your other functions, access any column to check whether it is empty or for adding data.

```
 if listview.Items.Item[0].SubItems[2]<>'' then //check if the fourth column of the listiew is empty
 listview.Items.Item[0].SubItems[2]:='Data col4' //adding the data
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a string to the fifth column of the first item of a listview:

```
ListView_SetItemText(ListView1.Handle, 0, 4, 'fifth column');
```

To get the string in the fifth column of the first item of a listview:

```
var
  ItemText: array [0..259] of Char;
begin
  ListView_GetItemText(ListView1.Handle, 0, 4, @ItemText, SizeOf(ItemText));
  ShowMessage(ItemText);
```

**edit:** Note that this method of adding a text to a subitem bypasses some VCL mechanism, for instance you can get a 'SubItem.Count' of '0' and still have the text on the subitem. If this is important I would use RRUZ's method.